# Is there any meaning behind Zoro's headband?

Tags: one-piece

When Zoro gets serious, he always wear his headband. Where did he get that? How did it become so important to him? Is there any back story about it (Maybe from a movie or something)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hachimaki , in particular: _worn as a symbol of perseverance, effort, and/or courage by the wearer._

Comment: I think that the answer is Kuina. When things get serious, he wears this deep blue bandana because he feels that he is fighting with kuina together. The hair of Kuina is deep blue, so that's another hint. If you remember, Zoro and Kuina promised to each other that one of them will be the greatest swordman. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any meaning or any special scene related to his headband.
According to the Wiki :-

> Zoro normally keeps a black bandanna tied around his left bicep and
>   ties it around his head when he is fighting seriously against an
>   opponent.

Atleast till now, nothing has been revealed about his headband. If it resembles something important, Oda Sensei will mention something about it in the future.
For now, we could just consider it as his style of dressing.

Comment: Even though it is not officially stated yet I love to believe this is to make his hair look black like Kuina's. He also wears a white shirt like she used to do so ah well :)

Comment: after time skip he doesn't wear white shirt. I love to believe that it is some keepsake from kuina or Something like the armband he wore during kuina's funeral.